# Can Chef Attributes be referenced from within the same attributes file?

Tags: chef-infra

If I have an attribute:

> default[:mycookbook][:attr_foo] = "foo"

can I refer to it in the same file, something like this:

> default[:mycookbook][:attr_bar] = default[:mycookbook][:attr_foo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, however the correct sytax is:

> default[:mycookbook][:attr_bar] = "#{default[:mycookbook][:attr_foo]}"

..essentially the attribute is wrapped with:

> "#{}"

Comment: I'm wondering, why this should work better. Essentially, you're wrapping your variable just in a string. The correct syntax (from ruby perspective) is the one in the question. From chef perspective, I'd say that you shouldn't access it through the `default` hierarchy level, but instead access `node[:mycookbook]`. Is this not working?

Comment: While this works, it can lead to weird bugs and unexpected behavior.
The variable assignment happens only when Chef evaluates this file, so if you override attr_foo, the value of attr_bar will not automatically update to reflect the change.

Comment: @StephenKing: I hadn't tried that, default is the syntax used for assignment in the attributes files, so I assumed it would be the same for a reference.

Comment: @avout: Good to know. What is a better (or best) way in this case?

Comment: @StephenKing is correct. `#default` and `#override` (and others) are the *setter* methods on the `node` object. The *getter* is `#[]`. So you should either write `node.default` to set an attribute (or `default` for short, IF you are inside an attribute file), or use `node['my_attribute']` to access the value. But as @avout said, referencing other attributes when setting some other attribute can lead to weird behaviour if you override it from another cookbook. One solution is to set the attributes inside a *recipe* instead of an *attribute file*, as recipes are processed later in the run.

Comment: This answer and most of these comments are untrue. The reason this works is actually because `"#{}"` is creating a new string object in memory whereas the assignment does not. You could just as easily call `.dup` on it and get the same result.